# Qt5 build with mingw-builds error _MCW_EM was not declared in this scope

Tags: qt, build, mingw, mingw32, qt5

the error:

```
..\..\corelib\tools\qlocale_tools.cpp: In function 'char* qdtoa(double, int, int
, int*, int*, char**, char**)':
..\..\corelib\tools\qlocale_tools.cpp:2257:25: error: '_MCW_EM' was not declared
 in this scope
..\..\corelib\tools\qlocale_tools.cpp:2257:33: error: '_MCW_DN' was not declared
 in this scope
..\..\corelib\tools\qlocale_tools.cpp:2257:41: error: '_MCW_RC' was not declared
 in this scope
Makefile.Release:5718: recipe for target 'tmp/obj/release_shared/qlocale_tools.o
' failed
mingw32-make[5]: *** [tmp/obj/release_shared/qlocale_tools.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[5]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt5/2012.11/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap'
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make[4]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt5/2012.11/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap'
Makefile:41: recipe for target 'sub-tools-bootstrap-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [sub-tools-bootstrap-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt5/2012.11/qtbase/src/tools'
Makefile:50: recipe for target 'sub-tools-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-tools-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt5/2012.11/qtbase/src'
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/qt5/2012.11/qtbase'
makefile:51: recipe for target 'module-qtbase-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Info:

windows 7 x64 pro sp1

[MinGW version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/)

[Qt5 from git](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt5)

Environment variables:

> C:\Python33\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\mingw\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Programming\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Programming\Git\bin

Old Environment variables:

> C:\Python33\;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\SystemTools\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Programming\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Programming\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance
>   Toolkit\;C:\cygwin\bin\;C:\MinGW\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web
>   Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET
>   Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Programming\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Programming\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Programming\Git\bin

Configure options I use (configuration seems to work fine, no errors):

> -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license -opengl desktop -nomake demos -nomake examples -nomake tests

make command (dah): mingw32-make

any help to how to resolve this will be much grateful!

edit1: I did some more research and it's seems to be something related to OpenGL, but nothing on how to resolve this.

edit2: I configure with -no-opengl and run mingw32-make, got the same error so, need more ides here.

edit 3: if I change this line

> _control87(oldbits, _MCW_EM|_MCW_DN|_MCW_RC);

in qlocale_tools.cpp to

> _control87(oldbits, MCW_EM);

it's run until I get this error:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQt5Cored0
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: So, did you managed to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lQt5Cored0

That was due to a bug in Qt’s source code itself, the bug sneaked into the Git repo because the developer tested it on MSVS, but didn’t realize that MinGW behaved differently. It has been fixed now (BTW because of that I did manage to compile Qt5 at the time with VS2012 command prompt); so if you fetch the latest code from Git it will work fine.